# Multiple conditions for password accepts passwords that it should not

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm encountering difficulties while creating a program where I need to verify a password based on the following conditions:

- The length should be greater than 6 characters.
- It should contain at least one digit, but it cannot consist of just digits.
- The rule involving numbers or containing only numbers doesn't apply to passwords longer than 9 characters.
- The string should not contain the word "password" in any case.
- It must contain at least 3 different (case-sensitive) letters or digits, even if it is longer than 10 characters.

I've attempted using conditionals, but the code is giving me wrong results. How can I solve this?

This is the code that I've already tried using conditionals:

```
def is_acceptable_password(password: str) -> bool:

    not_password = 'password' not in password.lower()

    if len(password) > 6 and any(map(str.isdigit, password))\
        and any(map(str.isalpha, password))\
            and not_password:
        return True
        
    elif len(password) > 9 and not_password:
        return True
        
    elif len(set(password)) > 2:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Comment: What errors is your code "giving" to you?

Comment: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prueba/Escritorio/py4m/#test.py", line 22, in <module>
    assert is_acceptable_password("short") == False
AssertionError"

Comment: when I testing my code with some inputs the code doesn't giving me the proper output:                                                                                                                  assert is_acceptable_password("short") == False
assert is_acceptable_password("short54") == True
assert is_acceptable_password("muchlonger") == True
assert is_acceptable_password("ashort") == False

Comment: "How can I solve this? I'm a little bit lost here."

Comment: "short" clearly satisfies `len(set(...)) > 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for password which you have listed must *all* apply, they are combined with logical *and*.

But you have written the code as if *any* of the conditions alone is sufficient to accept a password, you have combined them with logical *or*.

Instead of

```
if condition1:
    return True
elif condition2:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

you must write

```
if not condition1:
    return False
elif not condition2:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are breaches in your code, that allow to accept for example a super-short password such as `ab1`:

```
is_acceptable_password('ab1')
> True
```

You have multiple conditions that should apply in different combinations together:

- (1) `len(password) > 6`
- (2) has digits
- (3) has something other than digits
- (4) `len(password) > 9`
- (5) `not_password`
- (6) `len(set(password)) > 2`

According to the task the combinations of conditions satisfied should be of of the following:

```
(5) & (6) & (1) & (2) & (3)
OR
(5) & (6) & (4)
```

What you have is:

```
(1) & (2) & (3*) & (5)
OR
(4) & (5)
OR
(6)
```

Can you spot the difference?

**P.S.** I marked your implementation of `(3)` with a `*`, because in the task it says "It should contain at least one digit, but it cannot consist of just digits." and you are checking the existence of **digits** and **alpha** which is not quite the same. For example `1.` should satisfy the task, but not your code.

I would change (2) and (3) to something like

```
any(map(str.isdigit, password)) and not all(map(str.isdigit, password))
```